# Sentry authenticate by username in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

How do I configure sentry to authenticate by username rather than by email. All the examples I am finding all authenticate by email. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First publish the Sentry config:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

Then open file `app\config\packages\cartalyst\sentry\config.php` and edit:

```
'login_attribute' => 'email',
```